# Disable/remove HSTS for a website in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https, hsts

My https not supported website is getting re-directed to https by default. I tried removing hsts entry from chrome net-internal settings but it does not work & the redirection just keeps happening. My website is a subdomain like xxx.yyy.com where https is supported for yyy.com.

Is it due to that ? How do I fix this for sub-domain ?

**Note**: I am not sure if the main domain’s web server’s HSTS header specifies `includeSubDomains`. But it does not happen when I try in incognito window. I checked if cookie is stored for the site xxx.yyy.com but there is no cookie present.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to close all tabs

- Goto the network internals page of your browser by typing “chrome://net-internals/#hsts“ into the address bar.
- Type the domain name into the “Query domain” text field and click the corresponding button to check if there are settings present for your domain.
- If so enter the same domain in the “Delete domain” text field and click the button beside it.
- If you now check again with the Query Domain field you should be getting “Not found“ answer.

Comment: thank you so much for this!!